# Create a new version of a container and submit do docker hub

Tags: docker, dockerfile, containers

I have a container and I want to make a change to it.

It is hosted at docker hub, and I would like to change one of its commands to install an additional app.

I can see the individual steps in docker hub, but not the dockerfile itself (not sure why).

This is the command I want to change:

```
/bin/sh -c apk --update add --no-cache openssh bash zip && ....
```

I want to pull the container, change that line to include an additional package in the add command of apk.

I have been reading about the `docker commit --change` command but I am unsure how to exactly pinpoint the command I want to change. Do I reference it numerically, saying I want to change line #3?

I will then tag a new version and push, which I know how to do, but I am finding it hard to understand how to change this without `docker run -it [name] bash` and then push this, as I already did that and it appended a new command after the CMD command, and broke the container...

Comment: Why not change the Dockerfile and build a new image?

Comment: @ShayK how can I access the Dockerfile? I can't donwload it from docker hub, nor I know how to regenerate it. In docker hub I only see an option to pull the image, I can't see any dockerfile.

Comment: You can use that container as base image for your image and in your docker file add another RUN step which will install the additional package you require

Comment: @ShayK I don't have the dockerfile. If I pull the image, where can I find the dockerfile for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What hosted on docker hub is actually the image of the container. 
This image is hosted in layers. each docker file command represents a new layer. You can't actually change a single layer, You can however create a new docker file based on that image and add new layers.

```
FROM SOME_BASE_IMAGE
RUN apt-get update && \
 apt-get install -y SOME_PACKAGE
```

(assuming the image has apt package manager)
You'll then have to build the new image with docker build -t IMAGE_REPO:IMAGE_TAG ...

Comment: I should have the dockerfile but I might have done this in a different machine and did not version it. I was hoping to be able to rebuild the dockerfile somehow, because the solution you provide is not very robust. If I want to delete a package in the future, I would have to keep on adding layers instead of just removing the line that includes installing the package. I am unable to make changes to any of the steps.

Comment: You cannot change layers. It is recommended you keep your docker file in a way you can version it

Comment: Not only that, even if in later layer you'll remove a package it wont reduce the image size due to docker's layered image model. docker is not the same as some install script.

Comment: Exactly, that was why I wanted to try and restore the dockerfile...

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have access to the Dockerfile, you can't change anything in that container, you can only append more stuff (layers).

This means that, you can't change `/bin/sh -c apk --update add --no-cache openssh bash zip && ....` for something else, but if your intention is to install / remove more packages, you can do the following:

```
FROM the_container_you_want_to_change
RUN ...
```

Comment: Isn't there a way to rebuild the dockerfile based on what's on docker hub? And is there a way to commit the image and dockerfile to dockerhub to avoid this in the future?

Comment: @BlunT you can run the image, do the change and commit, but that's just the same as building the a new image using `FROM the_container_you_want_to_change`, that is, it just will add a layer with the changes

Comment: Is there a way to restore the dockerfile from the image somehow?

Comment: @BlunT you can try your luck with `docker image history image_id --no-trunc`. However this drastically depends on how was the image built. If using multi-stage for instance, you will miss information.